# How to authenticate users with Social Login (Facebook, Google) in a REST API backend with Spring Boot (separate React Frontend)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, oauth, facebook-access-token

I am currently working on a Spring Boot REST API. I have successfully added login using client credentials with Spring Oauth and Spring Security (I can successfully get access token and refresh token using `/oauth/token` endpoint).
But now I want to provide social login with Facebook and Google. As I understand, this is the flow.

1. User clicks Login with Social button in React frontend.
2. Then, he will be asked to grant access. (Still in React)
3. After that he will be redirected to the react front end with an access token.
4. Frontend sends that access token to the Spring Boot backend. (I don't know to what endpoint)
5. Then backend uses that access token to fetch details from the Facebook/Google and check whether a such user exists in our database.
6. If such user exists, backend will return access and refresh tokens to the frontend.
7. Now frontend can consume all the endpoints.

My problem is, I have no idea about the steps 4,5 and 6.
Do I have to make a custom endpoint to receive FB/Google access tokens?
How do I issue custom access and refresh tokens in Spring Boot?

I would really appreciate it if you could help me with this scenario.

Comment: The 2 endpoint created by Spring OAuth2 Client are : 
`/oauth2/authorization/YOUR_CLIENT_ID` Used to redirect the user to the social login and 
`/login/oauth2/code/YOUR_CLIENT_ID/?code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_SPRING&?state=STATE_GENERATED_BY_SPRING` used after the user logged in his social, this service is called to end the login flow.
You have to implement SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler in order to check if the user is or not in the DB ( `onAuthenticationSuccess` method).

Comment: I didn't understand if you have a login based on username and password.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes I have a login based on username and password. But the thing is, Spring boot is used for the REST API. My front end is in another domain (or subdomain). So I guess I will have to redirect using React and retrieve the access token and pass it to the backend, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flow it's the following:

1. Front-End calls spring to `/oauth2/authorization/facebook`(or whatever client do you wanna use)
2. Back-end respond with a redirect to Facebook login page(including in the query params, **client_id**, **scope**, **redirect_uri**(must be the same present on your developer console) and **state** which is used to avoid XSRF attacks, according to OAuth2 Standards)

you can see more details here https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.1

> state
> RECOMMENDED.  An opaque value used by the client to maintain
> state between the request and callback.  The authorization
> server includes this value when redirecting the user-agent back
> to the client.  The parameter SHOULD be used for preventing
> cross-site request forgery as described in Section 10.12.
> 3) Once the user log-in and accept whatever popup facebook or other services will show, the user will be redirected to the page present in "redirect_uri", this page should be a component of your ReactJs. The callback will come with some datas put in the query params, usually those params are two, state(it's the same you sent to facebook) and code(which is used from the BE to end the login flow).

4. Once facebook or whatever service, called you back, you have to take those 2 params, from the url(using JS for instance) and call the `/login/oauth2/code/facebook/?code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK&?state=STATE_GENERATED_BY_SPRING`
5. Spring will call the facebook service(with an implementation of `OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient`, using your secret_token, client_id, code and few other fields. Once facebook responds with the access_token and refresh_token, spring call an implementation of `OAuth2UserService`, used to get user info from facebook using the access_token created a moment before, at facebook's response a session will be created including the principal. (You can intercept the login success creating an implementation of `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`and adding it to your spring security configuration. (For facebook, google and otka in theory `OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient` and `OAuth2UserService` implementations should already exist.

In that handler you can put the logic to add and look for an existing user.

coming back to the default behavior

6. Once spring created the new session and gave you the JSESSIONID cookie, it will redirect you to the root (I believe, I don't remember exactly which is the default path after the login, but you can change it, creating your own implementation of the handler I told you before)

Note: access_token and refresh_token will be stored in a `OAuth2AuthorizedClient`, stored in the `ClientRegistrationRepository`.

This is the end. From now then you can call your back end with that cookie and the be will see you as a logged user. My suggestion is once you got the simple flow working, you should implement a JWT token to use and store in the localstorage of your browser instead of using the cookie.

Hopefully I gave you the infos you were looking for, if I missed something, misunderstood something or something it's not clear let me know in the comment.

**UPDATE** (some java samples)

My OAuth2 SecurityConfig :

NOTE:

> PROTECTED_URLS it's just : `public static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new NegatedRequestMatcher(PUBLIC_URLS);`

> PUBLIC_URLS it's just:  `private static final RequestMatcher PUBLIC_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher( new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v1/login"));`

> Also note I'm using a dual HttpSecurity configuration. (But in this case it's useless to public that too)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OAuth2ClientSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final JWTService jwtService;
    private final TempUserDataService tempUserDataService;
    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepo authorizedClientRepo;
    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService;
    private final UserAuthenticationService authenticationService;
    private final SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler; //This is the default one, this bean has been created in another HttpSecurity Configuration file.
    private final OAuth2TokenAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider2;
    private final CustomOAuth2AuthorizedClientServiceImpl customOAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
    private final TwitchOAuth2UrlAuthSuccessHandler oauth2Filter; //This is the success handler customized.

    //In this bean i set the default successHandler and the current AuthManager.
    @Bean("oauth2TokenAuthenticaitonFilter")
    TokenAuthenticationFilter oatuh2TokenAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        TokenAuthenticationFilter filter = new TokenAuthenticationFilter(PROTECTED_URLS);
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        return filter;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void setFilterSettings() {
        oauth2Filter.setRedirectStrategy(new NoRedirectStrategy());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider2);
    }


    @Bean
    public RestOperations restOperations() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/twitch/**").authenticated()
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable().authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider2)
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(oatuh2TokenAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .oauth2Login().successHandler(oauth2Filter).tokenEndpoint()
                .accessTokenResponseClient(new RestOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient(restOperations()))
                .and().authorizedClientService(customOAuth2AuthorizedClientService)
                .userInfoEndpoint().userService(new RestOAuth2UserService(restOperations(), tempUserDataService, authorizedClientRepo));
    }

    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean disableAutoRegistrationOAuth2Filter() throws Exception {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(oatuh2TokenAuthenticationFilter());
        registration.setEnabled(false);
        return registration;
    }
}
```

By the fact that my `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS` the cookie created by spring after the end of the OAuth2 Flow is useless. So once the process its over I give to the user a TemporaryJWT Token used to access the only possible service (the register service)
My TokenAutheticationFilter:

```
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
    private static final String BEARER = "Bearer";

    public TokenAuthenticationFilter(RequestMatcher requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher) {
        super(requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String token = Optional.ofNullable(httpServletRequest.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION))
                .map(v -> v.replace(BEARER, "").trim())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new BadCredentialsException("Missing authentication token."));
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token, token);
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(auth);
    }


    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
       response.setStatus(401);
    }
}
```

TwitchOAuth2UrlAuthSuccessHandler (This is where all the magic happens):

> This handler is called once the userService and the userService is called when the user calls api.myweb.com/login/oauth2/code/facebook/?code=XXX&state=XXX. (please don't forget the state)

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TwitchOAuth2UrlAuthSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepo oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepo;
    private final UserAuthenticationService authenticationService;
    private final JWTService jwtService;
    private final Gson gson;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        response.setStatus(200);
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", null);
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        cookie.setSecure(true);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        response.addCookie(cookie);
        Optional<OAuth2AuthorizedClientEntity> oAuth2AuthorizedClient = oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepo.findById(new OAuth2AuthorizedClientId(((OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication).getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), authentication.getName()));
        if (oAuth2AuthorizedClient.isPresent() && oAuth2AuthorizedClient.get().getUserDetails() != null) {
            response.getWriter().write(gson.toJson(authenticationService.loginWithCryptedPassword(oAuth2AuthorizedClient.get().getUserDetails().getUsername(), oAuth2AuthorizedClient.get().getUserDetails().getPassword())));
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().flush();
        } else {
            response.setHeader("Authorization", jwtService.createTempToken(((OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication).getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), authentication.getName()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return "";
    }


}
```

RestOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient (its responsable to take Access_token and refresh_token from FB)

```
public class RestOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient implements OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> {
    private final RestOperations restOperations;

    public RestOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient(RestOperations restOperations) {
        this.restOperations = restOperations;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessTokenResponse getTokenResponse(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest authorizationGrantRequest) {
        ClientRegistration clientRegistration = authorizationGrantRequest.getClientRegistration();
        String tokenUri = clientRegistration.getProviderDetails().getTokenUri();
        MultiValueMap<String, String> tokenRequest = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        tokenRequest.add("client_id", clientRegistration.getClientId());
        tokenRequest.add("client_secret", clientRegistration.getClientSecret());
        tokenRequest.add("grant_type", clientRegistration.getAuthorizationGrantType().getValue());
        tokenRequest.add("code", authorizationGrantRequest.getAuthorizationExchange().getAuthorizationResponse().getCode());
        tokenRequest.add("redirect_uri", authorizationGrantRequest.getAuthorizationExchange().getAuthorizationRequest().getRedirectUri());
        tokenRequest.add("scope", String.join(" ", authorizationGrantRequest.getClientRegistration().getScopes()));
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Discord Bot 1.0");
        ResponseEntity<AccessResponse> responseEntity = restOperations.exchange(tokenUri, HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(tokenRequest, headers), AccessResponse.class);
        if (!responseEntity.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK) || responseEntity.getBody() == null) {
            throw new SecurityException("The result of token call returned error or the body returned null.");
        }
        AccessResponse accessResponse = responseEntity.getBody();
        Set<String> scopes = accessResponse.getScopes().isEmpty() ?
                authorizationGrantRequest.getAuthorizationExchange().getAuthorizationRequest().getScopes() : accessResponse.getScopes();
        return OAuth2AccessTokenResponse.withToken(accessResponse.getAccessToken())
                .tokenType(accessResponse.getTokenType())
                .expiresIn(accessResponse.getExpiresIn())
                .refreshToken(accessResponse.getRefreshToken())
                .scopes(scopes)
                .build();
    }

}
```

UserService

```
public class RestOAuth2UserService implements OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> {
    private final RestOperations restOperations;
    private final TempUserDataService tempUserDataService;
    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepo authorizedClientRepo;


    public RestOAuth2UserService(RestOperations restOperations, TempUserDataService tempUserDataService, OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepo authorizedClientRepo) {
        this.restOperations = restOperations;
        this.tempUserDataService = tempUserDataService;
        this.authorizedClientRepo = authorizedClientRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        String userInfoUrl = oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getProviderDetails().getUserInfoEndpoint().getUri();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, String.format("Bearer %s", oAuth2UserRequest.getAccessToken().getTokenValue()));
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Discord Bot 1.0");
        if (oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getClientName().equals("OAuth2 Twitch")) {
            headers.add("client-id", oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getClientId());
        }
        ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>> typeReference = new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        };
        ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> responseEntity = restOperations.exchange(userInfoUrl, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), typeReference);
        if (!responseEntity.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK) || responseEntity.getBody() == null) {
            throw new SecurityException("The result of token call returned error or the body returned null.");
        }
        Map<String, Object> userAttributes = responseEntity.getBody();
        userAttributes = LinkedHashMap.class.cast(((ArrayList) userAttributes.get("data")).get(0));
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientId clientId = new OAuth2AuthorizedClientId(oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId(), String.valueOf(userAttributes.get("id")));
        Optional<OAuth2AuthorizedClientEntity> clientEntity = this.authorizedClientRepo.findById(clientId);
        if (!clientEntity.isPresent() || clientEntity.get().getUserDetails() == null) {
            TempUserData tempUserData = new TempUserData();
            tempUserData.setClientId(clientId);
            tempUserData.setUsername(String.valueOf(userAttributes.get("login")));
            tempUserData.setEmail(String.valueOf(userAttributes.get("email")));
            tempUserDataService.save(tempUserData);
        }
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Collections.singleton(new OAuth2UserAuthority(userAttributes));
        return new DefaultOAuth2User(authorities, userAttributes, oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getProviderDetails().getUserInfoEndpoint().getUserNameAttributeName());
    }
```

As asked this is all the code you need, just to give you another hint. When you call `/login/oauth2/code/facebook/?code=XXX&?state=XXX` the chain is the following:

1. RestOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient
2. RestOAuth2UserService
3. TwitchOAuth2UrlAuthSuccessHandler

I hope this can help you. Let me know if you need more explainations.

Comment: Again, thank you very much. Do you have any sample codes?

Comment: I haven't a clean one, but if you need it I can post a sample when I finish work .

Comment: Before i post some code , i need to know, if you wanna link the Account (user and pass) with the OAuth2 Login. Like a dual login setup. This is not clear

Comment: Not really. My intention is to compare user's email in Facebook with my database and log him in, or otherwise make him a new account using jis details from Facebook. Is this the common practice? Or should I link the Facebook account using facebook_id?

Comment: I would be really grateful if you could post some code.

Comment: Just to be clear about your answer. Suppose my front end is in `www.myweb.com` and API is in `api.myweb.com`, so first the front end calls `api.myweb.com/oauth2/authorization/facebook` and it responds with a URL. Now front end redirect the user to that url and after authorization he comes back to the front end with Facebook access code. Then, frontend again send a request to `api.myweb.com/login/oauth2/code/facebook/?code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK`, am I right about these steps?

Comment: In order to be more clear, `window.location.href = api.myweb.com/oauth2/authorization/facebook` this one is what you are supposed to do, once you did that spring will redirect you to facebook login page. When facebook login ends, you will be redirected to `www.myweb.com/callback?code=XXX&status=XXX` then you will redirect the user to `window.location.href = api.myweb.com/login/oauth2/code/facebook/?code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK.

Comment: To answer to your prev question. In my current project I have a dual auth, Credentials based and twitch based(OAuth2), my flow is, once the user is authenticated with twitch I see if there's a user in my db that has linked that twitch account, if there is i just authenticate it otherwise I redirect the user to a register page where he create an account(after the account will be linked to his twitch account)

Comment: I still have one problem. The authentication between frontend and backend is done with Spring Oauth2 access_token and refresh_token. So how do I get an access_token and refresh_token after redirecting to `window.location.href = api.myweb.com/login/oauth2/code/facebook/?code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK` ? It is not an AJAX request and as you mention it gives a cookie. But how do I get access_token and save it in Local Storage? @xTheDoctah

Comment: Your Spring server should **never** expose access_token or refresh_token that come from Facebook OAuth2 server. Those two values intended to be used from your server to refresh the access_token, and to do calls to facebooks API. When you call `api.myweb.com/login/oauth2/code/facebook/?code=xxx&state=DO_NOT_FORGET_IT`  spring automatically calls the facebook service that provides those 2 information.  This endpoint usually respond with an HTML page. You can modify its behaviour , just like i did in `TwitchOAuth2UrlAuthSuccessHandler `

Comment: After your Auth2 flow its over you have to manage your session somehow, (with a jsessionID cookie,  JWT Token or something else)

Comment: Yes, I am confused about after Oauth2 flow process. Suppose I receive all the data I need from Facebook and I check them against my database. How do I issue a JWT token (Similar to Oauth access token and refresh a user receives when he login using username and password) to my Frontend. In your `TwitchOAuth2UrlAuthSuccessHandler` I can see you are generating a JWT token.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235992/discussion-between-xthedoctah-and-section117).

Comment: How do I fetch that JWT token in a redirect. Am I not supposed to send an AJAX request?